# Progress Bar PyQt5 style Minecraft Forge

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a request on PyQt5 to which I am looking for a solution. I'm creating a videogame in Pygame and for uploading resources (images, audio etc) I would like to use PyQt5. I have already created a window with progress bar by following [this](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/widgets/) and modified it graphically (css, etc.).

My goal is to make the window in PyQt5 in the Minecraft Forge style, where, if you have, there is a white window with a progress bar, where mods, textures, etc. are loaded and the name is written under the loaded resource bar and the percentage (or in the case of Minecraft Forge the quantity, example: 74/1349)

The problem is that I can not understand how I should remove the button in the example and replace it so that every time a resource is loaded from the program, the progress bar is updated.

In my case, the "load class" is called when the "game class" is initialized.

To explain better, in PyQt5 I would like to create a window with the progress bar like this:
[image]




[image]

Where from the "game class" the resources are loaded and the progress bar for each resource loaded is updated, or otherwise something like that.

Edit for eyllanesc:

I tried with:

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.pbar.setGeometry(30, 40, 200, 25)
        self.pbar.setFormat("%v/%m")
        self.pbar.setMaximum(150)
        self.pbar.setValue(0)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('QProgressBar')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

    while True:
        g = input("aggiornare?")
        if g is "y":
            w.pbar.setValue(w.pbar.value()+1)
```

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.pbar.setGeometry(30, 40, 200, 25)
        self.pbar.setFormat("%v/%m")
        self.pbar.setMaximum(150)
        self.pbar.setValue(0)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('QProgressBar')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    while True:
        g = input("aggiornare?")
        if g is "y":
            w.pbar.setValue(w.pbar.value()+1)

        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.pbar.setGeometry(30, 40, 200, 25)
        self.pbar.setFormat("%v/%m")
        self.pbar.setMaximum(150)
        self.pbar.setValue(0)
        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.start(1000)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('QProgressBar')
        self.show()
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            g = input("aggiornare?")
            if g is "y":
                self.onTimeout()

    def onTimeout(self):
        self.pbar.setValue(self.pbar.value()+1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have also tried in other ways, but they are all similar to each other.

Comment: Your explanation is confusing, you could explain yourself better maybe supporting you in an image of what you want to obtain.

Comment: Also, show your code. Following a link elsewhere that you somehow adapted for your needs does not count.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not insert my code at the moment, because it has non-working parts inside that I am modifying for something else. That's why I linked the page from which I took a cue for the progression bar. The only thing I ask is how can I start the progress bar without the button and update it without a timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the text format you must use the [setFormat()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html#format-prop) method, you must set the maximum value through [setMaximum()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html#maximum-prop) and the current value through [setValue()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html#value-prop), in the following example I use QTimer to simulate the resource load:

**Complete code:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import  *

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.pbar.setGeometry(30, 40, 200, 25)
        self.pbar.setFormat("%v/%m")
        self.pbar.setMaximum(150)
        self.pbar.setValue(1)
        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.onTimeout)
        timer.start(1000)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('QProgressBar')

    def onTimeout(self):
        self.pbar.setValue(self.pbar.value()+1)

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Output:

[image]

---

In pygame one is in charge of generating an infinite loop but in PyQt one calls that loop through `app.exec_()`, that is, that loop is internal. So the `input()` should not be used directly since it locks that loop and generates the GUI behaves inadequately, what you should do is create another thread and run it there for it use `QRunnable` and `QThreadPool`, in addition to `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()` to update the values as shown below:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.pbar.setGeometry(30, 40, 200, 25)
        self.pbar.setFormat("%v/%m")
        self.pbar.setMaximum(150)
        self.pbar.setValue(0)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('QProgressBar')
        self.show()
        self.runnable = Runnable(self)
        QThreadPool.globalInstance().start(self.runnable)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def updateProgressBar(self):
        self.pbar.setValue(self.pbar.value()+1)

class Runnable(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, w):
        QRunnable.__init__(self)
        self.w = w

    def run(self):
        while True:
            g = input("aggiornare?")
            if g is "y":
                QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self.w, "updateProgressBar", Qt.QueuedConnection)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, that's what I was looking for! I only have one question to ask again. In your example, can I call the "onTimeout" function from an external class or function? Or should the call be part of the same class? In the sense, if after having created the window, the "onTimeout" function is called externally, is the progress bar updated anyway?

Comment: @GTRE you can call it directly but the timer part is optional, if you want to update it directly through `w.pbar.setValue(some_value)`. If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark my answer.

Comment: @GTRE Also I recommend you not to combine pygame libraries with PyQt, you can have inappropriate behaviors.

Comment: If it were an external call, how should I do? I made a few attempts now to try, using a while loop with an input and an if. When the answer was right, it was called "w.pbar.setValue (w.pbar.value () + 1)", but the window was blocked... I mean, I do not understand when it should be called.... I'm sorry if you bored, but there are not many guides that explain well...

Comment: @GTRE It shows the code that you have tried to give you a correct option, the blocking loops are not correct in a GUI.

Comment: @GTRE Obviously you have problems because you do not understand the logic of a GUI, PyQt in addition to using oop also uses event-oriented programming. Also, if you answered quickly, it would prevent me from getting bored.

Comment: I understand that the main problem is "sys.exit (app.exec _ ())" ... I do not understand the logic of the Gui because unfortunately I have recently started using PyQt5, and I have not found any great guides ...

Comment: @GTRE I have added an example of how to use it with `input()`.

Comment: Finally someone who explains it well XD I thank you very much for your help, but above all for your enormous patience.